# Entity Framework transaction for inventory system

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to learn how Entity Framework works.  I understand that EF SaveChanges is basically a wrapper around a transactional update.  I also understand that you can wrap two context's in a TransactionScope if necessary.

I am using the Code First approach.

What I dont understand is how I would do an update like

```
UPDATE Inventory SET Available = Available - 1 WHERE Available > 0
```

In other words - How do I ensure that there is at least X Available inventory before doing the update?

I suppose I could write code that looks at the inventory of the product and verifies that there is enough inventory to complete a purchase:

```
if (Product.Inventory - quantityToPurchase < 0) throw new Exception(..)
```

But what about in scenario where two customers attempt to buy at the same time and the object fetched from the database for each customer claims to have 2 items in inventory?  My logic above would not catch that.

How do I ensure that the SaveChanges() method only commits the changes to the object IF and ONLY IF `(Available - quantity)` is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework by default uses Optimistic Concurrency.  What I described in my original post is called Pessimistic Concurrency in EF.  There are two attributes that can be used to achieve this.

First is `Timestamp` which will create a `rowversion` column in the table.  EF will detect this automatically and will always add a `where` clause to the update comparing the value of the property from the entity to the value of the column in the database.  The `update` statement succeeds only if the two match. The `rowversion` column is incremented by the server automatically.  This ensures that you are always updating the same data that you have in memory (in the POCO). If someone else changes that row after you fetched it and before you updated it, the update will fail.

Second is `ConcurrencyCheck` which works simliar to `Timestamp`.  It will cause the value of the POCO property to be included in the `where` clause.  The big difference is that it will not update this column like the `rowversion` will.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out what you were after and posted it here!  I'm not sure the issue is a "concurrency" problem but I do see how you solved it using the same techniques as you would for concurrency management.  Either way, thanks for posting this b/c I learned something.

Comment: Its a concurrency problem because I do not want two users updating the inventory row at the same time, allowing for the possibility of overselling inventory.  Because EF loads data from the DB first, and then writes it back, there is the chance that two users could load data at the same time that says "we have 2 shirts in stock" and then both try to write back to that same row indicating that they each purchased 2 shirts.  That would mean that I've now oversold the shirts.  The above approach prevents this scenario by ensuring that the row you write to hasnt been modified since being read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this check when you are saving the entity by overriding the SaveChanges method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || 
                                            e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                .Select(e => e.Entity())
                                .OfType<YourEntityType();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        // Run business rule
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I think that is very similar to the approach I mentioned in my question.  That basically leaves business rules up to the application but offers nothing enforced at the database level.  While unlikely, this still allows the possibility of overselling inventory.

Comment: Correct, you are using Entity Framework so your data access layer will need to enforce rules other than key constraints, etc.  Your rule (don't oversell inventory) is a classic Business Rule which should be handled by the application anyway, not the database.